# jquery form submission in new window

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to set some header information and cookies with form submission using $('#formid').submit(); javascript code. Most of the site says that setRequestHeader is only working on ajax form submission. but i can not use the ajax method to submit the form.

my javascript code is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#leftNav a").click(function(event){

     event.preventDefault();
     href = $(this).attr('href');
     $("#dynamicform :input").remove();
     var querystringArray = href.split('?')[1].split('&');

     $("#dynamicform").attr("action", href.split('?')[0]);
     $.each(querystringArray, function(index, value) {
      var elementArray = value.split('=');

      if(elementArray[0]=='methodtype') { $("#dynamicform").attr("method", elementArray[1]);}
        $('<input>').attr({
            type: 'hidden',
            value: elementArray[1],
            name: elementArray[0]
        }).appendTo('#dynamicform');


     });
     usagelogsajax(href.split('?')[0],'ncrtester');
     xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Test', 'three');xhr.setRequestHeader('X-shashi', 'three');
     $('#dynamicform').submit();
  });

});



function usagelogsajax(url, user) {
$.get("usagelogs.php?url="+url+"&username="+user,function(responseTxt,statusTxt,xhr){
      if(statusTxt=="success");
        //alert("Usagelogs created successfully!");
      if(statusTxt=="error");
        //alert("Error: "+xhr.status+": "+xhr.statusText);
    });
}
```

And my page have link like
http://sitename.com/autologinSL3?readform=&userid=userid&methodtype=get&pwd=passowrd

How can i achieve my requirements.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you given a 404 page?

Comment: The link to your webpage does not work. Also, I can't really understand you and what do you want to achieve. Your explaining in your first paragraph is so confuse. Remember to use a correct grammar or atleast, enough to understand you.

Comment: I really tried to edit your post, but during the process I realised I have no idea what You want to achieve, please bo so kind and rewrite Your post so we can understand what You want Your website to do. PS You have a typo passowrd != password.

Comment: Set the `target` attribute of your form to `_blank`, just as you would do with links, to have the browser display the server response to the form submission in a new window/tab.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the target-attribute of the form ([see mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form)).
If you set target="_blank" the form will be submitted and the result will be shown in a new window.

Comment: my question is how can i set extra header information with form submission?